# QThread and Custom class

Tags: c++, qthread

i have develop a class MyDevice which is a C to C++ wrapper. I would to create thread in which all method from the class will be run.

I have define the class as below:

```
class DeviceMngr
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread DeviceThread;

public:
    DeviceMngr();
    ~DeviceMngr();
    void OpenDevice();
```

In the main.cpp, I have done :

```
DeviceMngr *MyDevice = new DeviceMngr;
```

What I want after is to move MyDevice to a Thread I thought using :

```
MyDevice->moveToThread(&DeviceThread);
```

After, I plan to create signal/slot to connect the main thread to the DeviceMngr one.

What is strange is that the moveToThread do not appear as autocompletion. The build do not recognize the movetothread.

Did I miss something in the Qthread ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your **DeviceMngr** class is not derived from QObject. [moveToThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) is instance method of QObject class.

So, to be able to use moveToThread, please derive your class from QObject first. This [link](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) might help.